# Vue/Cli Build custom Js

Tags: vuejs3, vue-cli-3

When I build with Vue/Cli, can I extract the files I want with the name I want?

main.js;

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import global from '../global.js';

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

I already get an error when I open the commented field below. How can I take the appropriate action

vue.config.js;

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  productionSourceMap: false,
  //output: {
    //chunkFilename: (pathData) => {
      //return pathData.chunk.name === 'global' ? 'globalprivate.js' : '[chunkhash].js';
    //},
  //},
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its works for me;

vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  productionSourceMap: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    entry: {
      global: ["./global.js"],
    },
    output: {
      filename: (pathData) => {
        return pathData.chunk.name === 'global' ? 'global.js' : '[name]_[id].js';
      },
    },
  },
});
```

and my dist folder;

[image]